# Hadoop-2.7.2: appendToFile: Not Supported error

Tags: hadoop

I installed the `Hadoop 2.7.2` independently in single node mode.

I created a `testfile.txt` successfully with this content

```
Hello world in HDFS!
```

But when I want to append lines to this file with this command:

```
bin/hadoop fs -appendToFile extraFile.txt testfile.txt
```

it throws this error:

```
appendToFile: Not Supported
```

I'm using `ubuntu server 14.04` on my virtual machine. Any comment is appreciated :)

Comment: How can I check that? with "jps"? @vefthym

Comment: Yes, or you can check the logs

Comment: Or, it you can simply type `bin/hadoop dfs -ls /` and see if it shows results or an error